# ReplaceAll method to replace an array of String in java

Tags: java, arrays, replaceall

I have an array of `String` like: `"11456811193903(admin 2016-03-01 11:16:23) (Sale)"`, I want to remove `" (Sale)"` from the array `String`. How to replace this in an array of `Strings`?

```
Original String:
String[] fileName = {"11456811193903(admin 2016-03-01 11:16:23) (Sale)"};

After replacing:
fileName:11456811193903(admin 2016-03-01 11:16:23)
```

Comment: despite the fact that the array only contains one variable, which might be just an example, you just have to loop over the array and use the [String#replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) method, if you simply want to replace a literal.

Answer (score 4):

Bahramdun's solution works perfectly fine, but if you are a fan of Java 8 streams you might want to use this:

```
String[] fileName = {...};
fileName = Arrays.stream(fileName)
                 .map(s -> s.replace("(Sale)", ""))
                 .toArray(size -> new String[size]);
```

Comment: You dont actually need to collect as a list and then convert to Array. A simple way would be: `fileName = Arrays.stream(fileName)                 .map(s -> s.replace("(Sale)", "")).toArray(size -> new String[size]);`

Comment: It says " Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 
  or above"

Comment: @SheenaTyagi yes you have to compile your code with/for Java 8 to use Streams.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this: If your array has more than one element, then you can loop over the array as shown below. And if it is only one sentence, then you can directly remove the `(Scale)` and assign it again to the `String fileName`

```
String[] fileName = {"11456811193903(admin 2016-03-01 11:16:23) (Sale)"};
for (int i = 0; i < fileName.length; i++) {
    fileName[i] = fileName[i].replaceAll("\\(Sale\\)", "");
}
System.out.println("fileName = " + Arrays.toString(fileName));
```

And it is the result:

```
fileName = [11456811193903(admin 2016-03-01 11:16:23)]
```